# How to fix submenus in CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive-design

I have a few problems with my CSS Submenu.

Please check my fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9XUJD/1

A few problems:

1. When you hover over `A element`, it gets pink background, but If you go over submenu, parent `A` element is losing it's background. How can I tell him that even when user opens submenu, parent `A` needs background ?
2. How can I tell my `.sub` element that It needs to have `auto width` so that expands to right if there are elements in it? If you check fiddle, I have two columns inside sub element, but it has a fixed width like it's parent.
3. Can my `.sub` element be responsive ? So that I have a max width with different breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/9XUJD/2/)

1. You need to use the `list item` hover state, not the link.

   This is the new selector:

   ```
   ul li:hover > a {
       background: #E94160;
       color: #fff;
       text-decoration: none;
   }
   ```
2. Just remove the `width` setting from `.column`. Block elements get 100% width by default.
3. Didn't quite understand but I think the fiddle answers your problems.